# How to remove 'Pay by Razorpay' badge on WooCommerce billng page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, razorpay

I'm setting up a new e-commerce website. And I've integrated Razorpay payments to the site for payment processing. It shows an image badge on the billing page that shows 'Payment by Razorpay'. I want it to be removed or hidden.

I tried to hide it via CSS but that image has CSS class, So I can't set it's CSS property to 'display: none;'

Comment: Can you share the HTML/CSS line of the element please or image that shows chosen element using F12?

Answer (score 1):

That badge is just an image, you can hide it by adding this CSS code below.

```
.wc_payment_method.payment_method_razorpay img {
    display: none;
}
```

> *Suggestion: Please read the Razorpay policy before doing this.*

Answer (score 0):

Using the [demo page](https://razorpay.com/demo/) on Razorpay, I think you can hide the button with this:

```
.pay {
    display: none;
}
```

[Original Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycQmg.jpg)

[With the CSS display:none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu8zu.jpg)

If this doesn't work for you, ¿Can you please provide the HTML/CSS of the page? Without that it is going to be difficult to help you in a specific manner.